# Images don't appear centered on mobile

Tags: css

The problem occurs in the images under the Get Tickets button on this page http://www.luaumakaiwa.com/Terms/tabid/71/Default.aspx
When you see the page with a mobile device the images don't appear centered but left-aligned.

The code is

```
@media(max-width:717px){
  .top-img-cont{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 207px;
                overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

I tried adding "margin: 0 auto;" to class top-img-cont but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
.top-img-cont img {
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful reply. This centered the first image but the second and third dont show up anymore on screen iPhone 6 landscape · width: 667px.

Comment: I see you have updated that page on your site.  Your images now seem to be displaying properly, but are stretched.  In your css on the .top-img-cont img target, you can leave width:200px, but change 'height' to 'auto'.  This will keep your images centered as your original request but will also keep them proportional.  I am editing this in my original answer, please mark as correct if you are satisfied.